# Storing a Pre-Hung Door

Tags: doors

I ordered a pre hung exterior steel door the other day, and now I don't think I will be available to install it the day it arrives. Is it better to pop the door out of the frame and store them separately, or leave the door in place? TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Keep the door in the frame. This will help prevent the frame from warping.

Store the door as upright as possible to prevent the frame (especially if it's wood) from warping. Even a steel door frame could bend a bit if it's stored at an angle.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. They're stood and leaned in stores and lumber yards for years. Unless you have extreme moisture exposure the wood will be fine. Most jambs are made from clear or finger-jointed boards and don't really warp, and you're straightening it all when you hang it properly anyway. (If you think hanging an exterior door mostly involves nails through brick mold, think again. :) )

Comment: They are, absolutely, leaned in all sorts of ugly directions at the store, but for _years_? That's a retailer that needs to reassess his stocking habits.

Comment: Some sizes are less popular, and lumber yards in particular have many dusty corners where returns and defectives linger.